# What is the project bin in kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

What is the *project bin*?

I went to [Kdenlive's manual](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Projects_and_Files/Project_Tree) and it says "The Project Bin is a view in Kdenlive which lists all the clips that are associated with the project." But the problem is, that doesn't mean anything.

- What is a view?
- Why does the project bin exist?
- What does the project bin do?
- Why does the project bin do what it does?

I keep reading these articles for beginners but the most basic questions remain unanswered and I was just wondering if you guys could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To add a few more aspects:

The project bin is a 'container' that can encompass items across multiple directories in the filesystem. That way you don't have to physically copy clips from scattered locations to a single working directory. but from the perspective of kdenlive, they are now all in one place when they're in the bin.

I believe this is a fairly generic concept which applies to other development software, like visual studio for example.

A view is just a smaller window within the kdenlive main window. there are so many sub windows in kdenlive they can't all be shown at once, so if you need to see something else, get rid of the project bin view.

Since project bin kind of glosses over the underlying file directory structure though, it doesn't take a very big project before you get hundreds or even thousands of items in the bin. therefore the bin has some extra features.

1. you can make virtual sub directories for it.
2. you can right-click any item and select 'locate' to find it in the physical directories.
3. a search bar... if you know part of the name of what you're looking for. if you don't, but you do remember where it is on the timeline, another way to go to an item in the bin is to right-click the item in the timeline, and select 'find in project bin'.

put it all together, and kdenlive project bin is about as fast and easy to use as anyone could want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also relatively new to KdenLive, but here is what I've learned about the Project Bin. This is where I drop video and/or image clips to add them to a project, from there I drag them onto the timeline to do the final editing.

As far as I understand it, you must load clips, images, or sounds into the project bin before you can actually use them in your project.

https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Projects_and_Files/Project_Tree

I see this same question cross posted on Reddit. More info there:
https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/mhs169/what_is_the_project_bin/